# The correct LINQ operation and response format

Tags: c#, linq

I have quite specific question...
In service I'd like to collect data from db table:

```
version IntData1 IntData2 IsProxy
1.0.1 5 8 true
1.0.8 4 4 true
1.2.1 1 0 true
2.0.0 12 5 false
```

And I have to make a response:

```
{
   "<version>": {
     "game" : {
        "IntData1": 13223,
        "IntData2": 13
     },
     "proxy": {
        "IntData1": 113223,
        "IntData2": 130
     }
   },
   ...
}
```

Well. I have pretty straightforward solution:

```
  public class StatisticsModel
  {
    public Statistics Game { get; set; }

    public Statistics Proxy { get; set; }
  }
```

and acting this way:

```
        var result = servers.GroupBy(x => new { x.Version.Major })
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key.Major + ".0.0", v =>
                new StatisticsModel()
                {
                    Game = new Statistics
                        {
                            IntData1 = v.Where(x => !x.IsProxy).Sum(sum => sum.IntData1),
                            IntData2 = v.Where(x => !x.IsProxy).Sum(sum => sum.IntData2),
                        }
                    Proxy = new Statistics
                        {
                            IntData1 = v.Where(x => x.IsProxy).Sum(sum => sum.IntData1),
                            IntData2 = v.Where(x => x.IsProxy).Sum(sum => sum.IntData2),
                        }
                });
```

***Names are changed***

As u can see it is not optimal and good looking IntData1 and IntData2 filling with x2 iteration (mb event x3).
Could u advice the better way?
I was thinking on Group by with multiple columns but failed making it work.

**Updated**
Well, I continued searching for solution and came up with that:

```
    var result = servers.GroupBy(x => new {x.Version.Major, x.IsProxy})
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Version = s.Key.Major + ".0.0",
            IsProxy = s.Key.IsProxy,
            StatisticsModel = new StatisticsModel
            {
                IntData1 = s.Sum(sum => sum.IntData1),
                IntData2 = s.Sum(sum => sum.IntData2),
            }
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Version)
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v =>
            new StatisticsLifeInfoModel
            {
                Game = v.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsProxy)?.StatisticsModel,
                Proxy = v.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsProxy)?.StatisticsModel
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution is any better, however it does only calculate the sums of the different sub groups once.

Here is the result of the code below:

```
[
    {
        "Version": "1.0.0",
        "Game": {
            "IntData1": 10,
            "IntData2": 12
        },
        "Proxy": null
    },
    {
        "Version": "2.0.0",
        "Game": {
            "IntData1": 13,
            "IntData2": 7
        },
        "Proxy": {
            "IntData1": 12,
            "IntData2": 5
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the code. Notice I didn't need to use a dictionary and used the `GroupBy` as you suggested in your OP. I split up the operations for clarity, but they can be combined.

The 1st part groups by both the Version.Major and IsProxy properties, so that the sums of the IntData properties can be calculated.

The 2nd part groups by version so that the data can be combined in a single JSON object, then splits out the IsProxy between the Game and Proxy properties of that JSON object.

Notice also I account for the scenario where a version might not have game or proxy data. Finally I did use your Statistics class, however it's unnecessary and I would normally just use an anonymous class. If you want to return a C# object, you should instead have a class that includes the Version, Game, and Proxy properties. However, if you just want to return the JSON, then just use anonymous classes and return the JSON string.

```
void Main()
{
    var sums = GetServers()
        .GroupBy(x => new { Major = x.Version.Major, IsProxy = x.IsProxy })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Version = $"{x.Key.Major}.0.0",
            IsProxy = x.Key.IsProxy,
            IntData1 = x.Sum(i => i.IntData1),
            IntData2 = x.Sum(i => i.IntData2)
        });

    var result = sums
        .GroupBy(x => x.Version)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Version = x.Key,
            Game = x.Any(i => i.IsProxy)
            ? new Statistics
                {
                    IntData1 = x.Where(i => i.IsProxy).First().IntData1,
                    IntData2 = x.Where(i => i.IsProxy).First().IntData2
                }
            : null,
            Proxy = x.Any(i => !i.IsProxy)
            ? new Statistics
                {
                    IntData1 = x.Where(i => !i.IsProxy).First().IntData1,
                    IntData2 = x.Where(i => !i.IsProxy).First().IntData2
                }
            : null
        }); 
    
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
    
    Console.WriteLine(json);        
}

public class Statistics
{
    public int IntData1 { get; set; }
    public int IntData2 { get; set; }
}

public List<MyTableEntry> GetServers()
{
    return new List<MyTableEntry> { 
        new MyTableEntry { Version = new Version { Major = 1, Minor = 0, Build = 1}, IntData1 =  5, IntData2 = 8, IsProxy = true },
        new MyTableEntry { Version = new Version { Major = 1, Minor = 0, Build = 8}, IntData1 =  4, IntData2 = 4, IsProxy = true },
        new MyTableEntry { Version = new Version { Major = 1, Minor = 2, Build = 1}, IntData1 =  1, IntData2 = 0, IsProxy = true },
        new MyTableEntry { Version = new Version { Major = 2, Minor = 0, Build = 0}, IntData1 = 12, IntData2 = 5, IsProxy = false },
        new MyTableEntry { Version = new Version { Major = 2, Minor = 0, Build = 1}, IntData1 = 13, IntData2 = 7, IsProxy = true }
    };  
}

public class Version
{
    public int Major { get; set; }
    public int Minor { get; set; }
    public int Build { get; set; }
}

public class MyTableEntry
{
    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public int IntData1 { get; set; }
    public int IntData2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsProxy { get; set; }
}
```